# Printer for applying royal icing

Tags: icing

Is there something like a printer that makes it easy to create icing art on cookies?

All the work to create the example below, I believe there is something that can facilitate production

[image]

Comment: Have you googled icing printer?

Comment: I have a 3D printer where I make cookie cutters.  I searched Google for a printer for other confectionery purposes.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this style of 'printer', where there's an arm that moves a pen used to be called a 'plotter', and 'icing plotter' finds a homemade one made out of Lego : https://boingboing.net/2018/01/04/cloggy-nozzles.html

Comment: And you might be able to apply the spots with a template, then outline and flood fill the rest to speed things up, even without anything automated

Answer (score 1):

The term I wanted to find is: Cookie Icing Machine domestic

According to [Joe's comment](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/108335/printer-for-applying-royal-icing/108380#comment172968_108335) I managed to find information I didn't know how to look for ...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AJYc3mPvRg

Comment: If I were building it, I'd probably go with a large syringe and some sort of linear actuator, so it was more consistent in how much it deposited per motor rotation.